# What should an iOS/Mac library do about persisting a mix of sensitive/insensitive data?

Tags: ios, macos, security, serialization, keychain

I'm putting together an iOS/Mac library that I intend to open source. Part of the library vends data which client applications are likely to want to persist. The data is a mix of insensitive and sensitive. I've been trying to work out the best way to handle this divide. I've considered a few options, but they all involve trade offs I'm unhappy with. Are there any typical best practices for this situation?

Some background:

- The class which stores this data is serializable via the NSSecureCoding protocol, but I only serialize the insensitive data.
- Objects are still valid if the sensitive information goes missing, though clients of the library would need to take the user through an authentication process again.

Options I've considered:

1. Read and write to the keychain automatically in -initWithCoder: and -encodeWithCoder:. This puts the least burden on the client, but is arguably "surprising" behavior. I've largely rejected this option, but I'd be happy to be talked back into it.
2. Include an API to save and retrieve the sensitive information. This is what I currently have implemented and it works well for simple cases. It does put a burden on clients to remember to send these messages, though, which I find somewhat inelegant.
3. Include an API to serialize/deserialize the sensitive information in a form which the client can store in the keychain on its own. This puts the most burden on the client, and is even less elegant, but also provides the most flexibility in how the sensitive information is stored (keychain groups, etc). Of course it also allows client code to mishandle the sensitive information - but I'm not sure it's up to my library to enforce proper storage.

I implemented #1 first, switched to #2, and am currently mulling over switching to #3. I'm also sure there are other options I haven't considered. Is there an established best practice for this sort of thing (that I just haven't figured out the right search terms to find)?